# Bulk Data Transfer through REST API

Tags: node.js, api

I have been informed that "REST API is not made / good for Bulk Data Transfer. Its a proven fact". I tried to search over google about this, but unable to find any fruitful answer. Can anyone let me know whether this statement is actually True or not? If its TRUE, then why?

Note: I am not exposing Bulk Data (50 million rows from database) over Web. I am saving it to Server as JSON format (Approx. 3GB file size) and transferring it to other system. I am using Node JS for this purpose. Network is not an issue to transfer file.

Comment: 50 million what? bytes? What have you heard and what were their arguments? HTTP and therefore REST deals perfectly fine with large responses. If you have an unreliable connection, Range support could help with resuming broken downloads.

Comment: No. 50 million rows from DB. JSON file size around 3 gb. Connection is not an issue.

Comment: Well then I'm curious what issues are you worried about, and what alternatives are you considering?

Comment: Actually still now I am not facing issue with my solution. But one person from Customer side commented this. We didn't argue as he is much senior than me. Hence I am trying to find out actual FACT & TRUTH.

Comment: It's a bit hard to comment on vague statements! Sucks that you don't work in a place where you can ask follow-up questions. Generally I think this will work fine. Large transfers have challenges, but that's true in any protocol. I've done plenty of work with multi-GB transfers over HTTP, I think it's a great protocol for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with exposing a end point which returns huge data

It might be concern on how you are sending that data, as memory could be a issue

Why don't you consider streaming the data, that way memory needed is only one packet of the data which has to be streamed at a time

NodeJS has many way to pipe the data into response object, you can also consider JSONStream module from npmjs.org